# Virtualbox dedicated network: client w. VM ubuntu webserver

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I found quite a few tutorials describing how to set up an ubuntu webserver for local web development as a VM in Virtualbox and assigning it a static IP address. Hm, that's fine as long as you stay within your home network.
this 
However, if working location independent, networks change and this likely causes connectivity issues.

So I figured it had to be set up on a separate network so working disconnected from an external LAN is possible.

Long story short - I want to be able to access my VM webserver without being connected to the internet/absence of an external DNS server.

Now, the server gets a second interface configured, that's the easy part. But how about the client? Disconnected from physical networks, there's no active interface... or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Set up Host-only networking. Therefore Virtualbox usually adds a virtual adapter for the host called vboxnet0 or similar, which than needs to be chosen in the machine's respective network adapter properties. Wasn't available on my machine though. However, you can create it via the "Global Settings" menu item.